# wire equation in verilog

Tags: verilog

If say I have the following wire set-ups, is the wire assignment all valid?

```
wire[3:1] w;
wire w1;
wire [1:0] w2;

A) w1 = w[2];    
B) w2 = w[1:0];  
C) w2 = w[1:2];
```

I am guessing that everything is valid....

Comment: Seriously Alex, you're going to have to try some of this stuff out for yourself.  It's OK asking for help on homework if you're really, really stuck - but a lot of your questions could be answered in 2 mins with a simulator.

The 'try it and see' way is a great way to learn things, and is the way most engineers learn the ins and outs of the CAD/EDA tools they use.  Also, there are plenty of free HDL simulators out there (OK, maybe one or two, Icarus springs to mind...).

Good luck! The world needs more engineers. Especially cool EEs like us!

Answer (score 1):

Don't guess.  Try to compile the code for yourself.  A and B are legal syntax.  C is illegal syntax, according to the simulators I tried (VCS and NC-Verilog), assuming you mean:

```
assign w2 = w[1:2];
```

The compile error message will be something like "Illegal part select range".

In the IEEE Standard for Verilog (Std 1364-2005), section 5.2.1 "Vector bit-select and part-select addressing", it is stated that the 1st number must address a more significant bit than the 2nd number.